# Git: What is the proper way for merging local branch with dev?

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I have several problems while merging my local code and pushing to remote. One of the biggest problems is getting lots of irrelevant classes as if I changed them when I use the following approach:

```
git add .
git commit -m "commit message"
git pull origin dev
(fix conflicts if occurs)
git push origin feature_branch
```

I think I need to use another approach e.g. updating my local dev with remote and merging my feature branch with local dev before pushing to remote. Assume that I have a local `feature_branch` feature branch and complete my changes. At this point, is the following approach is ok or is there a proper way?

```
git add .
git commit -m "commit message"
git checkout dev
git pull origin dev
(fix conflicts if occurs or reset my local dev to remote dev)
git checkout feature_branch
git merge dev
git push origin feature_branch
```

Note: Of course I can use `rebase`, but at this stage I just want to use `merge` with a proper way.

**Update:** Here is another approach using `stash` in order to prevent from irrelevant changes to be displayed. Is there any problem with this approach?

```
git stash push -m "feature_branch"
git checkout dev
git pull origin dev
(fix conflicts if occurs or reset my local dev to remote dev)
git checkout feature_branch
git merge dev
git stash apply stash@{n}
git add .
git commit -m "commit message"
git push origin feature_branch
```

Answer (score 1):

Your second example is functionally the same as the first, because your local dev branch should be identical to the remote dev branch, and only your feature_branch should have any conflicts.

So, your first approach is what I'd recommend: pull (==fetch origin; merge origin/dev), push.

Personally, I typically `git pull --rebase`; if that works flawlessly (i.e. no conflicts/automatically resolvable via rerere), you get a nice local development branch without a bunch of merge commits, if it doesn't, well, usually I just fix the rebase, but if that's too much work, I can still merge normally like you do.

Comment: Thanks a lot Marcus for these wonderful explanations. Could you pls have a look at my Update and give your recommendations for: **1)** Is there any problem with this approach? **2)** Can I shorten it by omitting `git checkout dev` part, etc.? Could you post a proper way using merge in your answer?

Comment: Any reply please?

Comment: 12 s after you've asked nobody can possibly have already replied to you.

Comment: also, nothing changes about my answer. Your stash makes no sense, this is all about things that are already in the index.

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is actually related to the code changes that are not related to me but seems to be as if I did them. For this reason, I just want to be clarified about the proper way.

Comment: your way 1 is the proper way, as I've repeated already.

Comment: But when using that approach I have encountered the problem that I mentioned. That's why I am looking a more suitable way actually. But as far as I see, there is no difference between 1st and 2nd approach. But to fix receiving the irrelevant file to be listed while merging, I thought to use stash. Now I am confusing  :(

Comment: Anyway, voted up for your helps. But as I have not enough repo, I can't :(

Comment: if you have things that you need to stash before pulling upstream, chances are you shouldn't stash them, but commit and merge them. This is really more of a basic "how do I git?" question than "how do I merge remote branches" question!